# How to convert actual frequency to normalised frequency?

Tags: matlab

I have two data sets ( which is 80*80 matrix) with relative risk ranging from -1.5 to +1.5.
I want to plot these two data sets as ine normalised frequency distribution plot.
How can I convert the actual frequency to normalised one( range 0 to 1)

So what I actually want is: if my frequency ranges from 0 to 200
( i want 0 to assign value of 0, 20 as 0.1, 40 as 0.2 , 60 as 0.3 .... 200 as 1)
So if the value of relative risk is -1 and actual frequency at this risk is 60 for dataset one and 80 for data set two, so in that case, I want -1 ( which is relative risk value) to show frequency as 0.3 and 0.4 for dataset one and two respectively after normalization. I need it in the same graph so that I could figure out the difference between two data sets.
This what I want my graphs axis to be:
Y-axis: normalized frequency for the following groups (ranging from 0 to 1)
X-axis; RR classes - <-1.5, -1.5 to -1.25, -1.25 to -1, -1 to -.75, -0.75 to -0.5, -0.5 to -0.25, -0.25 to 0, 0 to 0.25, 0.25 to 0.5, 0.5 to 0.75, 0.75 to 1, 1 to 1.25, 1.25 to 1.5 and >1.5

Comment: 1- Compute histogram. 2- Normalize histogram by dividing by sum. 3- Plot normalize histogram. Which of these steps do you have difficulty with?Showing some code always helps show what you have difficulty with, people can more easily see the gaps in knowledge or understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [matlab documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html):

```
% assuming a,b are your frequencies
figure; hold on;
histogram(a,'Normalization','probability');
histogram(b,'Normalization','probability');
```

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, I want to show the frequency values at -2,-2.5,-3,-3.5,-4 stacked in 1 bar, I am naming this  category as < - 1.5. What code should I write to do that?

Comment: I would probably use either `text` or label the x-axis using `xticklabels` functions. Here's also a nice description with copy-pastable code. 
>[Link](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91709-how-do-i-label-the-bars-in-my-histogram)<